# Does $a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ always exist s.t. $a_1 \cdot x \cdot a_2^c = x \cdot a_3^c \forall a_1, a_2, x, c \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

If

$$
B_1 = a_1 \cdot x \cdot a_2^c
$$

$$
B_2 =x \cdot a_3^c
$$

Does $a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ always exist s.t. $B_1 = B_2 \forall a_1, a_2, x, c \in \mathbb{R}$? And if yes, how to prove it?

Comment: If $a_1<0$, $x>0$, $a_2>0$ and $c$ is an even integer then $B_1<0$ but $B_2>0$ no matter what $a_3$ is chosen.

Comment: many thanks @lulu. In conclusion, by counter example, such a $a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ does not always exist, correct?

Comment: Correct. $\quad $

Comment: many thank @lulu